# iOS 7 Can't have audio via bluetooth receiver using AVAudioSession

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, ios7, bluetooth

I'm facing an issue using bluetooth for my app on iOS 7.
To be more precise, the bluetooth receiver i'd like to connect to is : http://www.amazon.co.uk/Sony-Bluetooth-Receiver-Enhancement-Smartphone-Black/dp/B00G9YK7LS

Of course the iPhone is paired to the device before I start testing.

My app should just make an audio pass through (from the mic to the speakers) using the EZAudio framework. It works fine using the iPhone headset but not with the bluetooth.

Here's the code I put in the delegate class (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function) to init the audio session :

```
// configure the audio session
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *err = NULL;

// deactivate session
[audioSession setActive:NO error:&err];
if (err) {
    NSLog(@"There was an error deactivating the audio session");
}

[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:&err];
if( err ){
    NSLog(@"There was an error creating the audio session");
}

[audioSession overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&err];
if( err ){
    NSLog(@"There was an error sending the audio to the speakers");
}

// Activate the session
[audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
```

Then I use EZAudio framework to send audio to the audio device:

```
/**
 Start the output
 */
[EZOutput sharedOutput].outputDataSource = self;
[[EZOutput sharedOutput] startPlayback];
```

Anyone has any idea about this issue please? Have I missed something?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No ideas? Nobody is facing the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should set the category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`. When you have it set to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`, the bluetooth device needs to be available for input as well as output. If it is not, the device will default to internal speakers for playback.